# PHP Library for Ethereum

Tags: php

I am looking for a PHP library to interact with Ethereum. Are there any active open source projects of PHP libraries for Ethereum available?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 12):

Here are couple of projects that are currently maintained:

ethereum-php https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php

go-ethereum client https://github.com/Achse/geth-jsonrpc-php-client

Comment: Do these projects interact with `metamask` as well, for example retrieving logged in account from `metamask`? @Mikko Ohtamaa

Comment: PHP is a server side language and Metamask is a browser (client) facing JavaScript solution. You need to understand that they live in different domains. A web browser can forward whatever comes out from MetaMask to the server.