# How to transfer tokens from smart contract using PHP?

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20, php

I want to transfer tokens using PHP script and that script will be executed using cronjob, is there library available to transfer by unlocking account using private key?

Comment: [https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26358/web3-js-php-implementation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26358/web3-js-php-implementation)    Hi. You can check here. It looks like web3 library on PHP is not yet fully developed, but there are some things you can do with it. web3.py for python is working fine. i had similar problem and I simply did it in python.