# How can i safely unlock an account and send transactions from a web application server using web3js?

Tags: web3js

I need a web application backend to be able to make transactions to a smart contract. In order to do this i need to send a transaction on behalf of an account that is authorized by our smart contract. How can i generate these transactions securely?

I read somewhere that using `web3.personal.unlockAccount` is not a safe approach because it exposes the password when communicating with the node. Is this true? And if so, what is the better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlocking an account on a remote node is unsafe for two reasons:

- you expose your password,
- anyone that has access to the node can transfer funds from the unlocked account.

So you should not unlock accounts on a node, unless it cannot be accessed via RPC or only from the localhost.

What you can do instead is that yozu sign the transaction locally and send it as a raw tramsaction to the remote node. There are different questions here on stack exchange that deal with how to do this, for example [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29904/how-to-unlockaccount-account-using-private-key-instead-of-password/29916#29916).

Comment: Is it safe to unlock an account on a local node running on localhost or will that expose the password as well? And how is the password exposed when unlocking on a remote node? does it send information unencrypted?

Comment: It's safe to unlock locally if you do not have the RPC interface enabled, which is the default configuration when you start geth. As far as I know, there is no encryption when you transfer the password to the node. So it is itransferred in plain text.